# Copying files, while preserving ALL attributes

Tags: windows, filesystems, copy

I'm trying to write a restore script for an embedded PC running Windows XP, the idea is, to plug in an restore USB flash drive, boot it and copy an image from the flash drive to the PC. That's working fine so far. However each embedded PC has an individual license file, which needs to be preserved.
I'm trying to copy these files to flash drive, restore the image and copy them back to the PC.
If I copy them using Windows Explorer, they are are ok.
If I copy them using command lines "copy" or "xcopy" they break. The also break when I use C# and File.Copy, so I guess there are some attributes which are not covered.
Any ideas how to copy these files without the need to log in (they usally don't have any kind of display or keyboard)?

Note that the license files are bound to hardware id, i'm  not trying to pirate anything.

Comment: Did you use xcopy with the /k parameter?

Comment: You're probably losing the Alternate Data Streams, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams.  Only NTFS supports them, so if your flash drive is FAT/FAT32/exFAT you'll need to store an archive rather than bare files.